# Inserting Values Into Table with Identity Column via Databricks

Tags: sql, hive, databricks

I've created a table in Databricks that is mapped to a table hosted in an Azure SQL DB.  I'm trying to do a very simple insert statement on a small table, but an identity column is giving me issues.  This table has the aforementioned identity column and three additional columns.

I first tried something similar to below:

```
%sql

INSERT INTO tableName (col2, col3, col4)
VALUES (1, 'Test Value', '2018-11-16')
```

That was giving me a syntax error, so I did some searching and learned that Hive SQL doesn't allow you to specify columns for an INSERT statement.  So then I tried something like below as a test:

```
%sql

INSERT INTO tableName
VALUES (100, 1, 'Test Value', '2018-11-16')
```

That gives me an error message that I can't insert explicit values into an identity column, but that's what I expected to happen.

If I can't specify the columns for my INSERT statement, how do I avoid issues when I have an identity column?  I just want to insert values for the non-identity columns, and I want the ID column to continue incrementing like normal.  The above example is extremely watered-down.  I will need to do much larger insertions based on SELECT statements eventually, so any solution involving toggling on IDENTITY_INSERT probably isn't feasible.

Comment: Try inserting `NULL`.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work.  I still get the following error message: 

`Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tableName' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

Comment: Hi Eric , did you find any solution ? I'm having the same issue. Thanks !

Comment: jegordon -- I did not.

Comment: Same issue here. Anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: The first example where the columns in the target table are individually specified works fine for me with Databricks 12.2 runtime. I'm not sure how else you'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how we can create a table with an identity column -
CREATE TABLE table_name
(column_name1 data_type GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
column_name2......)

Below are the two ways how we can insert the data into the table with the Identity column -

- First way -
  INSERT INTO T2 (CHARCOL2)
  SELECT CHARCOL1 FROM T1;
- Second way -
  INSERT INTO T2 (CHARCOL2,IDENTCOL2) OVERRIDING USER VALUE
  SELECT * FROM T1;

Links for reference-
Create table - https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html
Insert into table - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=statement-rules-inserting-data-into-identity-column